# mongorestore from stdin

Tags: mongodb, database-restore

On a remote server I have a file which is the mongodump output compressed, let me say a file called `mongodb.tar.gz`.

Inside `mongodb.tar.gz` there is a directory structure like this:

```
dump/dbname/
dump/dbname/blogs.bson
dump/dbname/blogs.metadata.json
dump/dbname/editors_choice.bson
dump/dbname/editors_choice.metadata.json
...
```

Is there anyway to restore this dump without download and uncompress entire file locally?

I mean something like:

```
curl http://remoteserver/mongodb.tar.gz | gunzip | mongorestore -d dbname
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only pipe compressed files which contain one collection.

You could do:

```
curl http://remoteserver/mongodb.collection.gz | gunzip -c | mongorestore -d dbname -c collectionname -
```

The `-c` gunzip option is needed so it writes to stdout and the last `-`so mongorestore expects input from stdin.

Tested with version 3.0.7 (doesn't work with v2.6.4).

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, this is not possible, at least not without writing something yourself.  The feature has been requested as [SERVER-4345](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4345) and [SERVER-5190](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5190) but there are several issues with an immediate implementation based on how the current tools work (i.e. it is not simple to do).

Answer (score 1):

Although only a partial answer, you could [use fuse](https://serverfault.com/a/138406/22213) to mount the .tar.gz file after downloading it.

Seeking a direct answer to the other part, I asked [question 730494](https://serverfault.com/questions/730494/remote-mount-tgz-file-over-http).

Answer (score 0):

Well I did it and it wasn't pretty. What I did was first extract *only* the metadatas from the tarball since they couldn't be directly piped into the mongorestore command which accepts only BSON.

After extracting the metadata I ran two restores: first the normal mongorestore with the folder as a parameter to restore the metadata.

Then in the second restore I read the file names of the BSON files from a file I had created earlier and for each file I untarred it to STDIN and piped the result to mongorestore. Yes it was messy but hey, it works!

To see the abomination in its full glory here's the repo: https://github.com/datascienceproject2019-codescoop/codescoop-models

And here's the script https://github.com/datascienceproject2019-codescoop/codescoop-models/blob/master/commands.sh

The restore script is in a different file since piping to docker exec is too difficult: https://github.com/datascienceproject2019-codescoop/codescoop-models/blob/master/gh_mongo_scripts/restore.sh

I used Mongo 4.0.6

EDIT: Buuut it is a lot slower to use streams than to just read from the extracted files. So I probably did this all for nothing since extracting temporarily 26 GBs of extra files isn't that big of a deal. Oh well.